# Formatting e-mails for optimal notification appearance

Tags: android, html, ios, css, email

So we have some e-mails that users subscribe to and get sent. They are HTML e-mails and they look good in (most) e-mail clients. But one issue is if you are getting your e-mails on your phone, you get the popup notification and those look a bit crap. For example, there is a company logo on the top of the e-mail and it appears on iOS it will include the "company logo" alt text in the notification (at least in Gmail it does).

Another issue is that close to the top of the email is a login link, which is important, because we want to encourage people to log in, but is wasted space when it appears on the popup notification on your phone. You can't actually click it from there anyway!

Are there any tags, attributes or CSS that can control what will or won't appear in the notification on iOS and Android? For example, if you had something like:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://somedomain.com/mycompanylogo.png" alt="My Company"/>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="http://somedomain.com/login">Click here to login!</a>
</div>
<div>
   <h2>Important alert title</h2>
</div>
<div>
   <!-- some important headline text that would be useful in the notification -->
</div>
<div>
   <!-- some more detailed stuff which would be fine not appearing in the notification -->
</div>
```

Is there a way to at least hint that the image alt and the "Click here to login!" should be part of what appears in the popup notification when a user receives an e-mail from us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so first out you state

> For example, there is a company logo on the top of the e-mail and it appears on iOS it will include the "company logo" alt text in the notification (at least in Gmail it does).

To fix this you will need a pre-header. A pre-header is a line which is hidden which you put at the very top of your HTML body. This means that the email client will read that before getting other content (for example your alt tag on your logo).

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<span style="display:none !important; visiblility:hidden; opacity:0px; color:transparent; height:0px; width:0px; mso-hide:all; max-height:0px; max-width:0px; line-height:0px; overflow:hidden;">Type your teaser content here.</span>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

In the above example of a preheader, you can see many different things going on. First up we have the `<!--[if !mso]><!-->` snippet. This will ensure anything encased between that and the `<!--<![endif]-->` statement will not be rendered in a Microsoft client. This is done because of Outlooks limited CSS support.

Next, we have a span stag with various CSS elements to hide the content within it. Then contained within the span tags is the content you'd want to appear in the preview of the email client.

For the issue with the login link appearing on mobile - you will want to use [CSS Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). These can detect the width of the device the email will be viewed on and you can apply styles accordingly. Here's an example I would use to hide your login link. This won't stop clients reading the link though so it is still recommended to use a preheader.

```
<head>
   <style>
      @media screen and (max-width: 630px) { //Selecting devices less than 630px
          .hide_on_mobile {display: none !important;} //Hiding anything that has the hide_on_mobile class
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
...
  <div class="hide_on_mobile"><!--Added the hide on mobile class-->
     <a href="http://somedomain.com/login">Click here to login!</a>
  </div> 
...
</body>
```

I do recommend to research a bit more into email CSS support as unlike the web we really don't have standards and it is a bit wonky. Campain monitor does have a good [CSS support guide](https://campaignmonitor.com/css/) for various email clients.

Comment: The pre-header is perfect. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes and `@media` queries to give you some of this ability. the concept is to block everything unless it meets your media query.

```
<style>
.outlook, .ios, .mobile, {
  display: none !important;
}
.desktop {
  display: block !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .outlook, .ios, .desktop, {
    display: none !important;
  }
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .ios {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .outlook, .desktop, .mobile, .ipad {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
</style>
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
.outlook {
  display: block !important;
  font-size; 16px;
}
.ios, .mobile {
  display: none !important;
}
.desktop {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

From here, you create messages with classes to send a custom message to each device.

```
<p class="desktop" style="display: none;">You're using a desktop device.</p>
<p class="mobile">You're using a mobile device.</p>
<p class="ios" style="display: none;">You're using an IOS device.</p>
<p class="outlook" style="display: none;">You're using Outlook.</p>
```

When the recipient receives the message, they get a custom message.

There are caveats. As created, this message will display, "This is a desktop device" to an iPad wider that 414px. You can fine-tune, but I'm too lazy to customize. It will work clumsily with Android devices, since they do not use @media queries and you cannot target them like you can IOS or Outlook. Finally, if you're using Gmail on an IOS device, you may need to fine-tune things further.

This at least gives you a way to target devices with one email, which might be useful if directing users regarding  device-specific updates.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/0mokhayq/

Good luck.

Comment: To be clear, this isn't about formatting the e-mail for a phone screen. It's about formatting it for the pop-up notification you get on your phone. That tiny snippet that appears to let you know you just got an e-mail. By default it just grabs the first couple of lines of text from the e-mail, which is often not optimal especially if there's some header stuff.

Comment: @MattBurland, you asked this: "Are there any tags, attributes or CSS that can control what will or won't appear in the notification on iOS and Android?" I just outlined how you would do that. You can be specific for IOS, Outlook and Android becomes generic. You can do this for the logo. Good luck.